# How to send button value to ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I try to send button values (integers) as page numbers to ajax function then to a php file, but can not get it work. Buttons are:

```
<form method="get" onchange = PageFunction(this.value)>
<button class = 'pages' type='button' onchange = 'PageFunction(this.value)' value="1">1</button>
<button class = 'pages' type='button' onchange = 'PageFunction(this.value)' value="2">2</button>
</form>
```

Ajax function is:

```
function PageFunction(page){
var ajaxRequest; 

if (page==""){
    document.getElementById("Pagination").innerHTML = "";
    return;
}else{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajaxequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
}

// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxequest.status == 200){

        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('Pagination');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "pathjobs-ajax2.php" + page, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you use jquery, you can use something like this `var x = $('.mybutton').attr('value');` -- js has this: `getAttribute("value");`

Comment: mate, try my solution below!

Answer (score 1):

mate, the button does not have onchange, try this :

```
<button class = 'pages' type='button' onclick = 'PageFunction(this.value)' value="2">2</button>
```

Comment: I changed them to "onclick" and got no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Without using jQuery

```
var PageFunction = function(val) {
  console.log(val);
  // ajax call here.
}

<form method="get" onchange = PageFunction(this.value)>
  <button class = 'pages' type='button' onclick = 'PageFunction(this.value)' value="1">1</button>
  <button class = 'pages' type='button' onclick = 'PageFunction(this.value)' value="2">2</button>
</form>
```

Using jQuery

```
$('.pages').on('click',function(e){
  console.log($(this).val());
  // ajax call here.
});
```

Comment: If I use non-jQuery option, should I put ajax codes before the ending '}'?  Sorry for the naive question, I have zero experience with jQuery.

Comment: For the jQuery option, does the following code make sense or not? $('.pages').on('click',function(e){
  console.log($(this).val());

    var ajaxRequest; 

    if (val==""){
        document.getElementById("Pagination").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }else{
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajaxequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxequest.status == 200){
      
    //codes too long, partially deleted
});

Comment: i would urge you to read basics of javaScript first, will help you a lot https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: I think so too.  Thanks a lot!